# Error: Invalid Use of Property when attemting to reset Excel UsedRange

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to reset the Excel 2007 UsedRange as per this discussion:
[Excel resetting "UsedRange"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751754/excel-resetting-usedrange)

However, I've encountered a problem that I do not understand. I get the error "invalid use of property" at compile time if I reset the UsedRange from a Worksheet object variable, but not via the Worksheets collection, as shown below:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

'Why does this not work?
ws.UsedRange

'And why does this instead?
wb.Worksheets(ws.Name).UsedRange

'Note: Absolute object variables are in use because this code will be used in
'an Access database to start & automate Excel. So the "Active_____." objects
'are not used, such as ActiveBook, ActiveSheet, etc.
```

It seems to me either way should work, but it's like something is missing from the code behind UsedRange that tells the compiler it's a command in addition to a property.

Comment: hi, try : a = ws.usedrange.cells.count , where a is a long variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
' Why does this not work?
ws.UsedRange
```

Because it doesn't "do" anything. It's just a range.

You can manipulate it like any other range, for example clear it:

```
ws.UsedRange.Clear
```

Comment: But it's not just a range. If you read the link that I referenced in my post, it can be called like a method. After reading that explanation, I'm now using this technique in my code and it works perfectly. I guess my OP is more about syntax than functionality. Here us the exact reference that says "if you call the property alone, it resets the UsedRange"... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752353/2705042 ... But as shown in my post, doing so only works in a certain way but not the other. And both of those ways look identical to me.....and that's what I was wondering about.

Comment: Hmm. It failed (compile error) for me, except for the syntax in my answer. Maybe in some cases or other versions than 2016, _Clear_ is a default method.

Comment: Hmm good point, I forgot to think about the version. I'm using 2007. Which syntax failed for you, and which worked..?