# Is there a known problem with using .UsedRange to reset the range in Excel, when the parent is a Worksheet object?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to ensure the UsedRange is accurate, having experienced it being substantially different to what is actually used in a worksheet. Having .UsedRange is meant to reset the used range to what is in use. I'm finding it doesn't unless structured in a very particular way.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' Works OK

Dim My_Sheet as Worksheet

Set My_Sheet = ActiveSheet

My_Sheet.UsedRange ' VBA compiler doesn't like this
```

Comment: You need to do something with that object too... Try this: `My_Sheet.UsedRange.Select` - Otherwise it's like putting a variable on a line all by itself, and that makes no sense.

Comment: Previously  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978949/error-invalid-use-of-property-when-attemting-to-reset-excel-usedrange  (and linked from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751754/excel-resetting-usedrange)  Note that (eg) `Worksheets(My_Sheet.Name).UsedRange` runs with no compile or runtime errors.

Comment: ... or `Dim My_Sheet as Object` would also work.  I don't know why there's a compile error when you Dim as `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tim Williams, dimming as Object has resolved it. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

@Geoff_B I don't have any issues. Do you mind sharing the screenshot? I tried different variations everything seems fine. unlikely the compiler confused with the expression.

[image]

```
Sub test()

Debug.Print ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address ' Works OK

Dim My_Sheet As Worksheet

Set My_Sheet = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

Debug.Print My_Sheet.UsedRange.Address

'=====================and=====================

Dim My_Sheet As Object

Set My_Sheet = ActiveSheet

Debug.Print My_Sheet.UsedRange.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: DavidLim - the issue is with .UsedRange by itself, which should reset the range. Change your line from:
Debug.Print My_Sheet.UsedRange.Address
to just:
My_Sheet.UsedRange
as per my example, and you'll get a compiler error.