# Blank/ empty columns are being printed because they were used and now are not

Tags: excel, vba

there are lot of people that have asked and answered a similar question but none of the suggestions are working for me. I have a sheet where the data ends in column 'S'. However, when I go to print it the preview shows an extra 8 columns on the right. When I apply a filter these same columns also get the filter added, even though they are empty (I checked if the cells were empty with =ISBLANK() and it returned true). If I highlight and delete the 8 columns, there is no difference in the print preview, however it does delete the filter.

I think I have just figured out why this is happening but I still do not know how to fix it. The data in the sheet that is causing the problems is copied from another workbook. The original data has an extra 8 columns within it. But I run a macro which formats everything and deletes these columns as they are either blank or unneeded.

So I think for some reason when I delete the 8 columns, 8 columns at the right most side of the sheet are added?

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Or what I should change to stop this happening.

Heres a snippet of one of the macros. This is the only piece of code that is deleting any columns.

```
    Range("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("H:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("K:L").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("L:M").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("O:O").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Range("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Crew"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Yes/ No"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "RPC"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SCE"
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Craft"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Frequency"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unit"
    Range("S1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Duration"
```

Comment: You should provide the codes you are using and explain how the data is being copied from the other workbook.

Comment: Not providing your code makes it difficult to answer, however it may require changing your print area using PageSetup.

Comment: @VBasic2008 The data is just manually copy and pasted in e.g. select all right click copy and then right click paste.

Comment: @DarrellH I just added some code in the question.

Comment: You should try to avoid `Select` and `ActiveCell`.  There is a lot of documentation on this site about how to avoid using those commands.  Also, no need to use `FormulaR1C1` to set a text value.  Simply use `Range("S1")="Duration"`

Answer (score 1):

See related 
[Excel resetting “UsedRange”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751754/excel-resetting-usedrange) and [Excel VBA usedRange Property and reset usedRange](http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-usedrange-property/)

I seem to recall that the last cell in the UsedRange is cached.  Meaning if you had typed something in column X (furthest right column in use), went about your business, then later cleared column X... then the UsedRange still goes out to column X despite there not being any filled in cells.  You'd have to either Save the file, or run some VBA against the UsedRange in order to clear the cached setting.

Answer (score 0):

I basically solved or did a work around for this. I wrote a piece of code that can go at the end of another macro or can be used as its own macro. It just sets the print area to be whatever size the used range is.

```
Sub printPrep()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .UsedRange.Address
    Debug.Print (rng.Address)
End With

End Sub
```